# Random embedding of $K_4$ in the unit square

Tags: probability, geometry, graph-theory, geometric-probability

Suppose I embed $K_4$ (the complete graph on 4 vertices) randomly in the unit square (using the uniform distribution for the positioning of the vertices). $K_4$ is *planar*, but not any embedding of it is a *plane graph*. What is the probability that the embedding will be a plane graph?

[**Edit:** when I say *embedding*, I mean an embedding of the vertices as points and embedding of the edges as straight line segments connecting their vertices; I am not sure this was clear]

Is the result different when we take the unit circle instead, or if we embed it in $\mathbb{R}^2$ using Gaussian distribution?

---

### Update

An equivalent question would be that: given a random triangle, what is the probability that a random selected point will lie in it. For the uniform distribution on the unit square, that had been asked already [here](http://people.missouristate.edu/lesreid/Adv41.html) and answered [here](http://people.missouristate.edu/lesreid/AdvSol41.html).

I have not verified the solution presented there, but if it is correct, the probability of the random embedding of $K_4$ in the unit square is $\frac{11}{144}$. This does not solve the unit circle case or the Gaussian case, however, and I am not convinced this should be similar at all.

Comment: Have a look at http://mathoverflow.net/questions/33112/estimate-probability-0-is-in-the-convex-hull-of-n-random-points.

Comment: Well, that's similar in some sense, but not quite helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand well your question, this is equivalent to the [Sylvester's Four-Point Problem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SylvestersFour-PointProblem.html).
You want to know the probability that one of the point is inside the triangle formed by the 3 other points.
When the points are i.i.d. uniformly in a square then it is $\frac{11}{36}$.
The probability $\frac{11}{144}=\frac14\frac{11}{36}$ you mentioned is the probability that the first point is in the triangle formed by the $3$ others, but we do not care which point is inside, so we should multiply by it $4$ to obtain the correct probability.

If the points are uniformly distributed in a disk (or more generally an ellipse) then the probability is $\frac{35}{12\pi^2}$ (see the previous link).

Comment: and I don't remember about when the points are normally distributed, but I think I heard it once. I might be able to find a reference if you are still interested.

Comment: It took me a while to read your answer, but it is helpful still, thanks!